# $f$ has a zero in its domain

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

If $f \in H(\Omega)$ holomorphic, and suppose that the set $A=\{z \in \Omega : |f(z)| \leq c \}$ is nonempty and compact for some positive constant $c$.
Then we need to show that $f$ has a zero in $\Omega$ and a zero in each connected component of $A$.

I think we can prove this by contradiction. Since $f$ is holomorphic, $A$ is compact then $\mathbb{C}-A$ is connected, so, and by Runge's Theorem, we can approximate $f$ by a sequence of polynomials $p_n(z)$ which converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$, if we can prove that each polynomial $p_n$ has a zero in $\Omega$, then so is $f$, I am not sure if this zero is the same for each polynomial in the sequence.

Comment: @Ted, what is $A$ in your example? I think I wrote all assumptions given in the question, $\Omega$ is a domain.

Comment: what is $\Omega$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ nonconstant since otherwise the hypothesis is not satisfied (level sets are either empty or full domain which is open).

Let $B=\{z \in \Omega : |f(z)| = c\}$ (compact by hypothesis) and $V$ the (bounded by hypothesis) open set $\{z \in \Omega : |f(z)| < c \}$. Note that $B$ is nonempty as otherwise $A=V$ open non empty so not compact and hence $V$ is non-empty too since otherwise $1/f$ is holomorphic and has a maximum modulus in $\Omega$ at a point in $B$.

Also $\partial V \subset B$ so for $U$ any component of $V$ (bounded of course as $V$ is), one must have a zero of $f$ in $U$ as otherwise $1/f$ is holomorphic in $\bar U$ and has a maximum there by compactness but not on $\partial U \subset B$, and again that is not possible.

The above implies that we have a zero of $f$ in each open component of $A$ and there is at least one such.

The statement about each component of $A$ is a bit ambiguous (think of the case when $B$ is a figure eight so $A$ has two open components but is connected), but it should be clear that each $w \in B$ is a limit point of both $V$ (otherwise apply maximum modulus to $1/f$ near that point) and $\Omega - A$ (by maximum modulus), so the components of $A$ contain at least the closure of one open component of $A$ (inclusion can be strict as noted in the figure eight example), hence the result follows

Comment: @Conard, is it true each component connected? Can we find an example of a domain $\Omega$ and a holomorphic function $f$ on $\Omega$ such that $A$ nonempty and noncompact for any positive $c$?

Comment: By definition a component means a connected component; $e^z$ on the plane satisfies the latter request where we get non empty half planes for each $c$ positive; it is actually difficult for holomorphic functions to satisfy the compactness condition ( entire implies polynomial, on the unit disc we get blaschke products etc)